# Retrieve all available shipping methods/carriers via REST

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, rest-api

We're looking for a way to generate a list of all available shipping method codes and shipping carrier codes via REST API. I'm only seeing this available via the cart but I'd like to be able to retrieve the list so that I could add the correct one to the cart. Does anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can get list of all available shipping method codes and shipping carrier codes via REST API. Using **Swagger extension.** (you can know more about swagger : https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-swagger-ui/)

Try **baseurl/swagger** (www/abc.com/swagger), call api for estimate-shipping-methods.
add params in body and also add cart id. then click on try it button.

You will get list of all available shipping method codes and shipping carrier codes in JSON Response.

Please see attached screen-shot.

[image]

Comment: My question regard shipping method, using observer. How can i get available shipping methods, so that what event i need to use and how to call in observer. magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Create your own REST API endpoint and get there shipping methods. Get active shipping methods and other info you need and thats all.