# Magento2 Shipping Methods rest api

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Is There any possibility to fetch all shipping methods using rest api in magento2

Thanks

Comment: check [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/216361/55928)

Comment: Hi @hits thanks for your reply, it is retrieving cart shipping methods, but i want all the shipping methods in magento

Answer (score 1):

A Shipping Methods in the Magento is based on cart. Without a cart you can't obtain desired result, because a methods could not do calculations by weight, by subtotal (min/max), by customer location etc. If you wish to obtain all available shipping carriers installed, you can parse store setting from the `carriers` section (but you should write own module with api access to this kind of data):

```
<?php
/**
 * Return array of carriers.
 * If $isActiveOnlyFlag is set to true, will return only active carriers
 *
 * @param bool $isActiveOnlyFlag
 * @return array
 */
public function getAvailableMethods($isActiveOnlyFlag = false)
{
    $carriers = $this->shippingConfig->getAllCarriers();
    foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierModel) {
        if (!$carrierModel->isActive() && (bool)$isActiveOnlyFlag === true) {
            continue;
        }
        $carrierMethods = $carrierModel->getAllowedMethods();
        if (!$carrierMethods) {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($carrierMethods as $methodCode => $methodTitle) {
            $methods[] = $carrierCode . '_' . $methodCode;
        }
    }

    return !empty($methods) ? $methods : [];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following based on your requirement

```
 - /V1/carts/:cartId/shipping-methods
 - /V1/carts/mine/shipping-methods
 - /V1/guest-carts/:cartId/shipping-methods
```

Reference file : `vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml`

Reference link : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/list.html